# Invalid Object Name - Local SQL Object

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following stored procedure works fine and returns data. However I wanted to also insert the data into a table for debugging before the final select. The code for the insert is commented out just before the final select. The insert uses the exact same select, without the order by, as the data source. However when I run the procedure with the insert uncommented I get an error:

Invalid Object Name BudgetSummaryDetail

I don't why using the object name is fine in the final select but if I try to use it for the insert I get an error. I'm sure there is a reason but I've tried it a bunch of different ways and I can't seem to figure it out. Any help or insight would be most appreciated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptBudgetSummaryTest]
@Fy AS CHAR(4),
@Index_No AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,       -- "IN" - NULL for all; otherwise, comma seperated list of values
@PCA AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,            -- "IN" - NULL for all; otherwise, comma seperated list of values
@Appro_Sym AS VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,      -- "IN" - NULL for all; otherwise, comma seperated list of values
@IncludeNonFundedPositions AS BIT = 1,  
@OnlyNonZeroPYs AS BIT = 0,
@OnlyNonZeroAllotment AS BIT = 0,           
@mrgpcain as dbo.mrgpcain READONLY

AS
IF 1=0 BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
END
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- SET XACT_ABORT ON causes the entire transaction to be
-- rolled back on a run-time error instead of just the sql
-- statement that caused the error.
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN

-- Tally tables for optional multi-value parameters

SELECT Item     
INTO #Index_No_ParamValues
FROM [Common].dbo.Split(@Index_No, ',')

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Index_No_ParamValues WHERE Item IS NOT NULL) < 1
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Index_No_ParamValues
END

SELECT Item
INTO #PCA_ParamValues
FROM [Common].dbo.Split(@PCA, ',')
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #PCA_ParamValues WHERE Item IS NOT NULL) < 1
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #PCA_ParamValues
END

SELECT Item
INTO #Appro_Sym_ParamValues
FROM [Common].dbo.Split(@Appro_Sym, ',')
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Appro_Sym_ParamValues WHERE Item IS NOT NULL) < 1
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Appro_Sym_ParamValues
END

;WITH
BudgetSummaryDetail
AS (
    SELECT
        tblPCAIn.FY,
        tblPCAIn.Index_No,
        tblPCAIn.PCA,
        tblPCAIn.Obj_Det,
        tblPCAIn.Agy_Obj,
        tblPCAIn.PYs,
        Calc_PYs = IIF(((tblPCAIn.Obj_Det='427' AND tblPCAIn.Agy_Obj='04') OR tblPCAIn.Obj_Det='439') AND (CAST(tblPCAIn.PCA AS INT) BETWEEN 5000 AND 5999), 
                        IIF(tblPCAFl.Fund_Src = 'F', (tblPCAIn.PYs * tblPCAFl.W_Pnct), 0), 
                        (tblPCAIn.PYs * tblPCAFl.Pnct)),
        Calc_Allot = IIF(((tblPCAIn.Obj_Det='427' AND tblPCAIn.Agy_Obj='04') OR tblPCAIn.Obj_Det='439') AND (CAST(tblPCAIn.PCA AS INT) BETWEEN 5000 AND 5999), 
                        IIF(tblPCAFl.Fund_Src = 'F', (tblPCAIn.Allotment * tblPCAFl.W_Pnct), 0), 
                        (tblPCAIn.Allotment * tblPCAFl.Pnct)),
        tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym,
        tblPCAFl.Fund_Src,
        tblPCAFl.Fund_No,
        tblPCAFl.Method,
        tblPCAFl.Project,
        PCT = ROUND(tblPCAFl.Pnct * 100, 0)
    FROM
        dbo.tblIndex AS tblIndex
        INNER JOIN @mrgpcain AS tblPCAIn ON
            tblPCAIn.FY = tblIndex.FY AND
            tblPCAIn.Index_No = tblIndex.Index_No
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblPCA AS tblPCA ON
            tblPCA.FY = tblPCAIn.FY AND
            tblPCA.PCA = tblPCAIn.PCA
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblPCAFl AS tblPCAFl ON
            tblPCAFl.FY = tblPCA.FY AND
            tblPCAFl.PCA = tblPCA.PCA
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblAppro AS tblAppro ON
            tblAppro.FY = tblPCAFl.FY AND
            tblAppro.Appro_Sym = tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym
        LEFT JOIN #Index_No_ParamValues ON
            tblIndex.Index_No = #Index_No_ParamValues.Item
        LEFT JOIN #PCA_ParamValues ON
            tblPCAIn.PCA = #PCA_ParamValues.Item
        LEFT JOIN #Appro_Sym_ParamValues ON
            tblAppro.Appro_Sym = #Appro_Sym_ParamValues.Item
    WHERE
        (#Index_No_ParamValues.Item IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM #Index_No_ParamValues)) AND
        (#PCA_ParamValues.Item IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM #PCA_ParamValues)) AND
        (#Appro_Sym_ParamValues.Item IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM #Appro_Sym_ParamValues)) AND
        (((@IncludeNonFundedPositions = 0) AND
            (tblPCA.PCA <> '02727')
        ) OR (@IncludeNonFundedPositions = 1)) AND
        (((@OnlyNonZeroPYs = 1) AND
            (tblPCAIn.PYs <> 0.0)
        ) OR (@OnlyNonZeroPYs = 0)) AND
        (((@OnlyNonZeroAllotment = 1) AND
            (tblPCAIn.Allotment <> 0)
        ) OR (@OnlyNonZeroAllotment = 0))
)

--DELETE FROM tblBS_Test
--INSERT INTO tblBS_Test
--SELECT * FROM (
--SELECT 
--  tblIndex.Dept_Id,
--  tblIndex.Dpty_Id,
--  tblIndex.Brch_Id,
--  tblIndex.Div_Id,
--  detail.Index_No,
--  tblIndex.Index_Title,
--  detail.PCA,
--  tblPCA.PCA_Title,
--  PROGLINK = REPLACE(tblPCA.Program+tblPCA.Element+tblPCA.Component+tblPCA.Task, '', '0'),
--  FUNDLINK = tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym+tblPCAFl.Fund_Src+tblPCAFl.Fund_No+tblPCAFl.Method+ IIF(tblPCAFl.Project = SPACE(6), SPACE(8), tblPCAFl.Project+'00'),
--  tblAppro.Ref,
--  detail.Obj_Det,
--  detail.Agy_Obj,
--  PYs,
--  POS = IIF(((detail.Obj_Det = '003') AND (RTRIM(detail.Agy_Obj) = '')), detail.Calc_PYs, 0.0),
--  Calc_PYs = detail.Calc_PYs,
--  detail.Calc_Allot,
--  PCT
--FROM 
--  BudgetSummaryDetail AS detail
--  INNER JOIN dbo.tblIndex AS tblIndex ON
--      tblIndex.FY = detail.FY AND
--      tblIndex.Index_No = detail.Index_No
--  INNER JOIN dbo.tblPCA AS tblPCA ON
--      tblPCA.FY = detail.FY AND
--      tblPCA.PCA = detail.PCA
--  INNER JOIN dbo.tblPCAFl AS tblPCAFl ON
--      tblPCAFl.FY = tblPCA.FY AND
--      tblPCAFl.PCA = tblPCA.PCA AND
--      tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym = detail.Appro_Sym AND
--      tblPCAFl.Fund_Src = detail.Fund_Src AND
--      tblPCAFl.Fund_No = detail.Fund_No AND
--      tblPCAFl.Method = detail.Method AND
--      tblPCAFl.Project = detail.Project
--  INNER JOIN dbo.tblAppro AS tblAppro ON
--      tblAppro.FY = tblPCAFl.FY AND
--      tblAppro.Appro_Sym = tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym
--  INNER JOIN dbo.tblAgyDE AS tblAgyDE ON
--      tblAgyDE.Obj_Det = detail.Obj_Det AND
--      tblAgyDE.Agy_Obj = detail.Agy_Obj
--  INNER JOIN dbo.tblObjDe AS tblObjDe ON
--      tblObjDe.Obj_Det = tblAgyDE.Obj_Det
--  INNER JOIN dbo.tblCat AS tblCat ON
--      tblCat.Category = tblObjDe.Category) as myda

SELECT 
    tblIndex.Dept_Id,
    tblIndex.Dpty_Id,
    tblIndex.Brch_Id,
    tblIndex.Div_Id,
    detail.Index_No,
    tblIndex.Index_Title,
    detail.PCA,
    tblPCA.PCA_Title,
    PROGLINK = REPLACE(tblPCA.Program+tblPCA.Element+tblPCA.Component+tblPCA.Task, '', '0'),
    FUNDLINK = tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym+tblPCAFl.Fund_Src+tblPCAFl.Fund_No+tblPCAFl.Method+ IIF(tblPCAFl.Project = SPACE(6), SPACE(8), tblPCAFl.Project+'00'),
    tblAppro.Ref,
    detail.Obj_Det,
    detail.Agy_Obj,
    PYs,
    POS = IIF(((detail.Obj_Det = '003') AND (RTRIM(detail.Agy_Obj) = '')), detail.Calc_PYs, 0.0),
    Calc_PYs = detail.Calc_PYs,
    detail.Calc_Allot,
    PCT
FROM 
    BudgetSummaryDetail AS detail
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblIndex AS tblIndex ON
        tblIndex.FY = detail.FY AND
        tblIndex.Index_No = detail.Index_No
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblPCA AS tblPCA ON
        tblPCA.FY = detail.FY AND
        tblPCA.PCA = detail.PCA
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblPCAFl AS tblPCAFl ON
        tblPCAFl.FY = tblPCA.FY AND
        tblPCAFl.PCA = tblPCA.PCA AND
        tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym = detail.Appro_Sym AND
        tblPCAFl.Fund_Src = detail.Fund_Src AND
        tblPCAFl.Fund_No = detail.Fund_No AND
        tblPCAFl.Method = detail.Method AND
        tblPCAFl.Project = detail.Project
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblAppro AS tblAppro ON
        tblAppro.FY = tblPCAFl.FY AND
        tblAppro.Appro_Sym = tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblAgyDE AS tblAgyDE ON
        tblAgyDE.Obj_Det = detail.Obj_Det AND
        tblAgyDE.Agy_Obj = detail.Agy_Obj
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblObjDe AS tblObjDe ON
        tblObjDe.Obj_Det = tblAgyDE.Obj_Det
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblCat AS tblCat ON
        tblCat.Category = tblObjDe.Category
ORDER BY 
    tblIndex.Dept_Id,
    tblIndex.Dpty_Id,
    tblIndex.Brch_Id,
    tblIndex.Div_Id,
    detail.Index_No,
    detail.PCA,
    tblPCAFl.Appro_Sym+tblPCAFl.Fund_Src+tblPCAFl.Fund_No+tblPCAFl.Method+ IIF(tblPCAFl.Project = SPACE(6), SPACE(8), tblPCAFl.Project+'00'),
    detail.Obj_Det,
    detail.Agy_Obj

IF Object_id('tempdb..#Index_No_ParamValues') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Index_No_ParamValues;
END

IF Object_id('tempdb..#PCA_ParamValues') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #PCA_ParamValues;
END

IF Object_id('tempdb..#Appro_Sym_ParamValues') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Appro_Sym_ParamValues;
END

RETURN 0
END

GO
```

Comment: This is how CTEs work.  They are only valid for that particular statement.  If you want to use it for multiple statements, you might want to insert the data into a temp table.

Comment: So what you are saying is I can only use BudgetSummaryDetail once? Just making sure I understand.

Comment: If you're using a CTE, yes.  It's essentially a pre-defined sub-query.  At the end of the statement, it is no longer able to be used.

Comment: Essentially it would only be in context for that `DELETE` statement. Once the INSERT statement hits your CTE is no longer in context so you get an error. You could stick your CTE first above the INSERT. Then again above your final SELECT and it would all work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. It makes perfect sense and I've been able to adjust the SP accordingly to get my desired result. Thanks again!